# Sorting 2-D array in descending order using lambda expression

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, lambda

I am working through some interview questions and came across this one. I understand thoroughly the code except what the next line does:

```
Arrays.sort(pair, (a, b) -> (b[0] - a[0]));
```

**Given scores of N athletes, find their relative ranks and the people with the top three highest scores, who will be awarded medals: "Gold Medal", "Silver Medal" and "Bronze Medal"**.

> Example 1: Input: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] Output: ["Gold Medal", "Silver
>   Medal", "Bronze Medal", "4", "5"] Explanation: The first three
>   athletes got the top three highest scores, so they got "Gold Medal",
>   "Silver Medal" and "Bronze Medal".  For the left two athletes, you
>   just need to output their relative ranks according to their scores.

```
 public class Solution {

   public String[] findRelativeRanks(int[] nums) {

        int[][] pair = new int[nums.length][2];

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            pair[i][0] = nums[i];
            pair[i][1] = i;
        }

        Arrays.sort(pair, (a, b) -> (b[0] - a[0]));

        String[] result = new String[nums.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                result[pair[i][1]] = "Gold Medal";
            }
            else if (i == 1) {
                result[pair[i][1]] = "Silver Medal";
            }
            else if (i == 2) {
                result[pair[i][1]] = "Bronze Medal";
            }
            else {
                result[pair[i][1]] = (i + 1) + "";
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is calling the `Arrays.sort` method to sort the array `pair` using a `Comparator` defined with a lambda expression.  The lambda expression can be used whenever type inference can figure out that we need an object of a class that only needs one function to be defined.

See http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html#section2 for more on the syntax.

Under the hood the function will be called many times with pairs of elements in the array and will be sorted from "smallest" to "largest" according to the comparison function.  If the function returns a negative number, then `a` will be considered "larger" than `b`, if it returns a positive one then `a` is "smaller" than `b`, and if `0` then it is a tie.

The trick here is that the comparison function returns `b[0] - a[0]` which is the opposite direction from usual.  As a result it will be sorted largest to smallest.  The largest is, of course, the gold medal winner.  Followed by silver, then bronze.

Comment: How does Java knows they are comparing the first column instead of the second and how if does the second column "follow" the order of the first one. Also, what is the meaning of a and b, is b the next item in the iteration? Thanks for the answer

Comment: @RodrigoProença The function accepts 2 elements in the array.  The fact that your lambda expression starts off `(a, b) -> ...` names them `a` and `b`.  The structure of what is in the array is determined by how you built it.

Comment: @btilly Is here should be reversed? In case lambda body is (a[0] - b[0]), `If the function returns a negative number, then a will be considered "larger" than b`, would it be "smaller"?